# sorting an array based on proximity to mean

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, mean, qsort

I have an array of doubles.  I calculate the mean of the array.

I now need to sort the array based on the proximity of each value to the mean.

If I could pass a special comparator function to qsort that took the mean as a 3rd parameter then it would solve my problem:

```
int compareValues(double a, double b, double mean)
{
    double aValue = fabs(mean - a);
    double bValue = fabs(mean - b);
    if (aValue > bValue)
       return 1;
    else if (aValue < bValue)
       return -1;
    else return 0;
}
```

However, from everything I have read, you cannot pass such a comparator to qsort.

Is there a simple way to do this that I am not seeing?

Comment: Without using some sort of global variable (don't do that), it is not possible to do this with `qsort`.

Comment: On BSD and Mac OS X, there is: `void qsort_r(void *base, size_t nel, size_t width, void *thunk, int (*compar)(void *, const void *, const void *));` where the `thunk` is passed as the first pointer to the comparator function. _The `qsort_r()` function behaves identically to `qsort()`, except that it takes an additional argument, `thunk`, which is passed unchanged as the first argument to function pointed to `compar`.  This allows the comparison function to access additional data without using global variables, and thus `qsort_r()` is suitable for use in functions which must be reentrant._

Answer (score 2):

Build your own specialized quicksort function:

```
int comp(double a, double b, double mean)
{
    a = fabs(mean - a);
    b = fabs(mean - b);
    if (a > b)
       return 1;
    else if (a < b)
       return -1;
    else return 0;
}

void swap(double *v, int a, int b)
{
    double temp;

    temp = v[a];
    v[a] = v[b];
    v[b] = temp;
}

void sort(double *v, int left, int right, double mean, int (*comp)(double, double, double))
{
    int i, last;

    if (left >= right) return;
    swap(v, left, (left + right) / 2);
    last = left;
    for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++) {
        if (comp(v[i], v[left], mean) < 0)
            swap(v, ++last, i);
    }
    swap(v, left, last);
    sort(v, left, last - 1, mean, comp);
    sort(v, last + 1, right, mean, comp);
}
```

Comment: I would go with a generic comparator function type like `int (*comp)(const void *, const void *, const void*)`, while I'm at it. Otherwise this sort function can just be used for this particular instance of a comparator with state

Comment: +1 Like this approach as I've wanted to do similar things in the past.  In a general solution, the 3rd variable is some sort of pointer to a state.

Comment: Your swap code swaps pointers, not the data that is pointed at.  That is consistent with the `sort(void *v[], …)` declaration, but requires you to sort an array of `double *`, not an array of `double`.  It works OK with a brute force cast when given an array of `double *`, but that isn't quite what was required.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Yes you are correct, which I discovered when I tried to pass my array of doubles as the first arg.  Is there a way to alter the code so that it will accept an array of doubles, not double pointers?

Comment: @user994179: yes, there are ways to do it — the BSD `qsort_r()` approach is sound and provides precedent.

Comment: Given that the sort function takes a `double *`, there's no obvious reason why the comparator takes two `void *` values and a double. You could tie it to the `double` type more completely, passing values instead of pointers to the comparator.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just throwing an idea, I haven't thought this through, but you could try to build a class for the comparator, and in the initialization define the `mean` as a global member.

Also, you can create a parallel array as follows:
    newArray[i] = fabs(mean - oldArray[i]);

and sort the old array according to the new one.

Comment: That wouldn't be C (rather C++) but a similar thing could be done with structs ( though it's a bit gross ).  Trying to work it out

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that you cannot pass such comparator to `qsort`, it is also true that you can store the value of the mean in a static variable outside both the comparator and the function calling `qsort`, and use a regular, two-argument comparator that "knows" to get the mean from the static variable:

```
static double mean;

int compareValues(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    double a = *((double*)pb);
    double b = *((double*)pa);
    double aValue = fabs(mean - a);
    double bValue = fabs(mean - b);
    if (aValue > bValue)
       return 1;
    else if (aValue < bValue)
       return -1;
    else return 0;
}

void call_sort(double *data, size_t count) {
    mean = find_mean(data, count);
    qsort(data, count, sizeof(double), compareValues)
}
```

The unfortunate consequence of this approach is that your sorting function is no longer re-entrant.

Comment: Yes I thought about that, but I've given up global variables during Lent.

Comment: @user994179 Static variables are not globals - they are invisible outside the translation unit.

Comment: Sorry my bad.  Not sure what a "translation unit" is, but I will find out.

Answer (score 1):

@merlin2011 now deleted answer had the germ of a good idea.

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, 
    int (*compar)(const void *a, const void *b));
```

The compare function passed to `qsort` takes pointers (and not doubles).  Further, `qsort()` will never call `compar()` with `NULL` parameters.  Thus the compare function could first be called with `a == NULL` and the `b` could point to state information.

```
int compar(const void *a, const void *b) {
  static void *state = NULL;
  if (a == NULL || b == NULL) {
    return Setup_State(&state, a, b);
  }
  return Do_normal_compare(state, a, b);
}
```

The complexity and re-entrant compatibility of `Setup_State()` could be quite elaborate, but a simple non-re-entrant example follows.

```
int Setup_State(void **statep, void* a, void *b) {
  *statep = b;
  return 0;
}

int Do_normal_compare(void *state, void* a, void *b) {
  double da = *((double *) a);
  double db = *((double *) b);
  double dmean = *((double *) state);
  return OP_compareValues(da, db, dmean);
}

// usage 

double mean;
compar(NULL, &mean);
qsort(d_array, N, sizeof(double), compar);
```

Maybe a call with `b == NULL` could signal some sort of post state clean-up.

```
compar(NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the "build your own `qsort`" answer more.  But you *could* do something like this.

Instead of sorting a list of doubles and an external mean, I'm sorting a list of structs which each store a pointer to a double and (the same) mean.

I sort *that* array, then list out the values of the result.

Seems to work,  but ends up being a lot worse than what @AlterMann did.

`gcc -o cmp cmp.c -std=c99 -Lmath`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int compareValues(double a, double b, double mean)
{
    double aValue = fabs(mean - a);
    double bValue = fabs(mean - b);
    if (aValue > bValue)
       return 1;
    else if (aValue < bValue)
       return -1;
    else return 0;
}

typedef struct dbl_and_mean_t{
    const double* value;
    const double* mean;
} dbl_and_mean;

int cmpToMean(const void* a, const void* b){
    dbl_and_mean* dma = (dbl_and_mean*)a;
    dbl_and_mean* dmb = (dbl_and_mean*)b;

    double aValue = *(dma->value);
    double bValue = *(dmb->value);
    // we assume mean is same in both cases.
    double mean = *(dma->mean);
    return compareValues( aValue, bValue, mean );
}

/*
       void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
                  int(*compar)(const void *, const void *));
*/

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    unsigned int numlen = 100;
    double numbers[100] = {
 20.11267454572858, 27.00916748845121, 41.69273886807976, 59.574594859929206, 5.148795948275042, 25.0952600949092, 7.490782458661016, 46.82558348995649, 99.1505635434539, 80.82884752229698, 34.562195425918965, 12.83419004171462, 65.21675903144343, 60.939055397544415, 59.716932510808405, 68.58214712201324, 16.96903326566488, 40.890117173893096, 43.24295370982686, 49.74083920053604, 51.879578222761545, 85.55201465227584, 0.9988146850440804, 72.9927624741183, 24.544352584593764, 38.07294449540915, 89.21601198806061, 46.242113823416055, 34.77013261276065, 75.50489987606491, 68.73075063359678, 34.11250399830412, 33.03497314824547, 50.356507540969574, 43.44185408674688, 1.3480391491077937, 17.87324689034111, 27.521463721587523, 65.36478555088043, 89.08983557487836, 91.20949281863321, 36.15883451406319, 64.71929705431249, 96.51660222081459, 84.3925334284804, 9.273474377948954, 20.7970994809055, 81.63173897647613, 34.54178336906219, 69.17908602857048, 34.49554788014096, 27.658713128591337, 37.84762296714004, 32.47882877578083, 80.33388365434217, 12.535403896961606, 1.6177858463917616, 58.492589297744544, 4.996882418234216, 0.6516899504362961, 94.14913555948795, 45.01455399721226, 91.13032884578304, 0.9747543756017163, 87.73797888418335, 17.05103955970504, 34.9990215191348, 32.132359722564175, 51.39141618413181, 90.41510433921886, 70.85275376557709, 60.81740079574899, 56.276844928014334, 96.84741168778665, 38.587969750110915, 26.93423429759396, 56.28727064877738, 40.69208717486249, 30.893466414304214, 54.69704130793473, 8.422991004598423, 42.51756379315109, 6.109299688810255, 97.5321480398511, 76.34912536352495, 83.6200551607522, 19.447640061947336, 29.659746702311896, 72.24996303415246, 7.992406225268933, 57.09202659164654, 60.782606246000036, 60.398430869817474, 41.77937462471086, 47.28376403551421, 54.31179044336384, 39.837395485680894, 39.301123086537395, 71.8438289228498, 49.209926974123285
    };
    double mean, sum = 0;
    dbl_and_mean* doubles_and_mean = calloc( numlen, sizeof(dbl_and_mean) );
    for( unsigned i = 0; i < numlen; i++){
        sum = sum + numbers[i];
        doubles_and_mean[i].value = &(numbers[i]);
        doubles_and_mean[i].mean = &mean;
    }
    mean = sum / numlen;
    printf("Mean is %f\n", mean);
    qsort( doubles_and_mean , 100, sizeof(dbl_and_mean), &cmpToMean);
    for( unsigned int i=0; i< numlen; i++){
        printf("%03d: %f\n", i, *(doubles_and_mean[i].value) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code given by [David Ranieri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1606345/david-ranieri) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22274206/15168) is a hybrid, semi-generic sort function.  Here is a reimplementation of the BSD `qsort_r()` function which is a fully generic variant of `qsort()` that provides a 'context' (or 'thunk') to the comparator function.

The code includes test data, and outputs:

```
Mean:   3.4940
Before:
[0] =   3.1416 (delta =   0.3524)
[1] =   2.7813 (delta =   0.7127)
[2] =   1.6130 (delta =   1.8810)
[3] =   9.8126 (delta =   6.3186)
[4] =   0.1213 (delta =   3.3727)
After:
[0] =   3.1416 (delta =   0.3524)
[1] =   2.7813 (delta =   0.7127)
[2] =   1.6130 (delta =   1.8810)
[3] =   0.1213 (delta =   3.3727)
[4] =   9.8126 (delta =   6.3186)
Mean:   5.1282
Before:
[0] =   1.2300 (delta =   3.8982)
[1] =   3.2900 (delta =   1.8382)
[2] =   8.1800 (delta =   3.0518)
[3] =   2.5100 (delta =   2.6182)
[4] =   4.1800 (delta =   0.9482)
[5] =   9.9900 (delta =   4.8618)
[6] =   6.7500 (delta =   1.6218)
[7] =   1.0100 (delta =   4.1182)
[8] =   4.6800 (delta =   0.4482)
[9] =   8.2100 (delta =   3.0818)
[10] =   6.3800 (delta =   1.2518)
After:
[0] =   4.6800 (delta =   0.4482)
[1] =   4.1800 (delta =   0.9482)
[2] =   6.3800 (delta =   1.2518)
[3] =   6.7500 (delta =   1.6218)
[4] =   3.2900 (delta =   1.8382)
[5] =   2.5100 (delta =   2.6182)
[6] =   8.1800 (delta =   3.0518)
[7] =   8.2100 (delta =   3.0818)
[8] =   1.2300 (delta =   3.8982)
[9] =   1.0100 (delta =   4.1182)
[10] =   9.9900 (delta =   4.8618)
```

This is based in part on some code I've been playing with that parameterizes the partitioning function from various implementations of the rest of the quick sort, so it is split up a little more than it might be otherwise.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
** Implement BSD qsort_r() under the name Qsort_r()
**
** void qsort_r(void *base, size_t nel, size_t width, void *thunk,
**              int (*compar)(void *, const void *, const void *));
**
** The qsort_r() function behaves identically to qsort(), except that it
** takes an additional argument, thunk, which is passed unchanged as the
** first argument to function pointed to compar.  This allows the
** comparison function to access additional data without using global
** variables, and thus qsort_r() is suitable for use in functions which
** must be reentrant.
*/

typedef int (*Comparator)(void *, const void *, const void *);

extern void Qsort_r(void *base, size_t num, size_t size, void *thunk, Comparator cmp);

static
void swap(void *val1, void *val2, size_t size)
{
    char temp[size];

    memmove(temp, val1, size);
    memmove(val1, val2, size);
    memmove(val2, temp, size);
}

/* Generate random number in range p..r inclusive */
static size_t random_int(size_t p, size_t r)
{
    assert(p <= r);
    size_t q = rand() % (r - p + 1) + p;
    return q;
}

static inline size_t thin_partition_random(void *base, size_t size,
    size_t lo, size_t hi, void *thunk, Comparator cmp)
{
    /* Use a random element as the pivot */
    assert(hi > 0);
    size_t m = random_int(lo, hi - 1);
    swap((char *)base + size * m, (char *)base + size * lo, size);

    /*
    ** Set l and r and move the array elements such
    ** that for all i in [lo..r), a[i] <= pivot,
    ** and for all i in [r+1..hi), a[i] >= pivot.
    */

    size_t l = lo + 1;
    size_t r = hi;
    while (l < r)
    {
        if (cmp(thunk, (char *)base + size * l, (char *)base + size * lo) <= 0)
            l++;
        else
            swap((char *)base + size * l, (char *)base + size * --r, size);
    }

    /* Put pivot element into place */
    swap((char *)base + size * lo, (char *)base + size * --l, size);
    return r;
}

/* Sorts the elements of a between low and high inclusive */
/* Sort short sub-partition recursively and iterate to sort longer */
void Qsort_r(void *base, size_t num, size_t size, void *thunk, Comparator cmp)
{
    size_t low = 0;
    size_t high = num;

    while (low < high)
    {
        size_t r = thin_partition_random(base, size, low, high, thunk, cmp);
        size_t l = r - 1;
        assert(l >= low && high >= r);
        if (l - low > high - r)
        {
            if (high - r > 1)
                Qsort_r((char *)base + size * r, high - r + 1, size, thunk, cmp);
            high = l;
        }
        else
        {
            if (l - low > 1)
                Qsort_r((char *)base + size * low, l - low + 1, size, thunk, cmp);
            low = r;
        }
    }
}

/* -- Test harness -- */

#include <stdio.h>

static void dump_array(int n, double *d, double mean)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("[%d] = %8.4f (delta = %8.4f)\n", i, d[i], fabs(d[i] - mean));
}

static
int comp(void *thunk, const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
    double aValue = fabs(*(double *)thunk - *(double *)pa);
    double bValue = fabs(*(double *)thunk - *(double *)pb);
    if (aValue > bValue)
       return 1;
    else if (aValue < bValue)
       return -1;
    else return 0;
}

static void test(int n, double *d)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += d[i];
    double mean= sum / n;

    printf("Mean: %8.4f\n", mean);
    printf("Before:\n");
    dump_array(n, d, mean);
    Qsort_r(d, n, sizeof(double), &mean, comp);
    printf("After:\n");
    dump_array(n, d, mean);
}

int main(void)
{
    double d[] = { 3.1416, 2.7813, 1.613, 9.8126, 0.1213 };
    enum { NUM_D = sizeof(d) / sizeof(d[0]) };
    test(NUM_D, d);

    double data[] =
    {
        1.23, 3.29, 8.18, 2.51, 4.18, 9.99,
        6.75, 1.01, 4.68, 8.21, 6.38,
    };
    enum { NUM_DATA = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]) };
    test(NUM_DATA, data);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that it is not production ready because it uses the standard library function `rand()`, and a good library function should not do that — calling this function could wreck the repeatability of program.  A decent alternative uses the [`drand48()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/drand48.html) family of functions instead, and specifically runs with its own seed and state, using:

- `long nrand48(unsigned short xsubi[3]);`

which returns a value in the range [0, 2<sup>31</sup>).  Getting a suitable seed is another problem that is soluble, but tends to be solved per platform.

---

Note that Linux (or GNU C Library) also implements [`qsort_r()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html), but the interface is different from the BSD version:

```
void qsort_r(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
             int (*compar)(const void *, const void *, void *),
             void *arg);
```

The two interfaces are equivalent but different.  The BSD version passes the auxilliary data as the first argument to the comparator, whereas Linux passes it as the last argument to the comparator.  Also, in the call to `qsort_r()`, the BSD version passes the auxilliary data pointer before the comparator, and the Linux version passes it after the comparator.  The only good news about the difference is that code created for one of the two interfaces will not compile cleanly for the other.