# How can i use the qsort_s function in my c program?

Tags: c, iso, qsort

I found qsort_s function in [C Refenence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort), which can provide a another parameter, which offers context information, to the compare function that compared to the qsort function.
However, the signature of qsort_s function in the mingw64's(x86_64-13.2.0-release-win32-seh-ucrt-rt_v11-rev0) header file under my Win11 is different from that in C Reference. And I even can't find that function in Linux!
What can I do? Thanks.

I've check the C Reference and the ISO document, and qsort_s exists indeed in stdlib.h accroding to them.

Comment: are you using c11 standard?

Comment: Check the Microsoft documentation.

Comment: The header file you refer to may be declaring [Microsoft’s version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/qsort-s?view=msvc-170) of the `qsort_s` routine, which is incompatible with the standard C version. You should show the declaration. Never describe a problem merely by saying something is different. Always show and explain the difference.

Comment: [`qsort_s()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.6.3) is defined in Annex K of the C11 and C18 standards; it is an optional part of the standard.  Annex K contains some problematic functions and has not been implemented by the GNU GlibC team — so `qsort_s()` won't be available on Linux.  There is a `qsort_r()` — but be aware that BSD and Linux both define it but disagree on how it should be defined.

Comment: You have two problems - The "secure" `_s` functions are all optional, so not available everywhere. And also, even though Microsoft provided the spec used in the C standard, that is not always the signatures they have in their own library. So limited usefulness!

Comment: See [Do you use the TR 24731 'safe' functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/372980/15168) and [Why didn't GCC or GlibC implement `_s` functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50724726/15168)— also [Sorting an array based on proximity to mean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22274067/15168), and [Sorting a multidimensional array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47151134/15168), and [Different declarations of `qsort_r()` on Mac and Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39560773/15168).

Comment: And  [Pass extra parameter to comparator for `qsort()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4210689/15168)

Comment: Note that Linux's `qsort_r()` has the same signature as Annex K `qsort_s()`, so you can swap `qsort_r()` and `qsort_s()` safely on Linux (as you can `strtok_r()` and `strtok_s()`).  BSD `qsort_r()` differs — you need a different comparator function as well as a different calling sequence.